# How to catch an error in power query when the issue is with excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am importing an excel file that has known errors like #N/A and #REF.  Power query will error out until the excel is fixed.  Well, I don't want to fix the errors in excel.  I just want power query to ignore them.  It won't.  Even when I click remove errors.  I tried try if xxx then xxx otherwise yyy or try error otherwise, but it still comes out as an error.  Is there a fix?

Comment: Do you need to do anything with the formula's from Excel? If not, could you possibly make all data copypaste as values before Power query?

Answer (score 0):

Replace all errors with null:

```
= Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Previous Step", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Previous Step"), each {_, null}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Option (1) Replace Errors on the column causing the [XLOOKUP( ] #N/A error in excel with 0 (on my test)
Option (2) Remove Errors on the same culprit column, but you get .RemoveRowsWithErrors(so each "entire" rows is removed.
Curiously, if the errors are resolved in Excel, the values in PowerQuery come back when "Apply Changes" or "Refresh" is executed, even if either Replace/Remove Error stays in the query script. [image]